# How to get a HttpModule to fire for *all* file extensions using IIS6

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6, httpmodule, isapi

I've learned enough researching this problem to surmise that this is only possible using a wildcard mapping to "aspnet_isapi.dll". I've also read that this is also not recommended, but I've found no other way to get the HttpModule for any extension.

The reason I can't simply do it this way is that trouble occurs for the ".asp" extension. I get a "This type of page is not served" message when trying to access ASP files, even if the ASP file only has plain HTML, or has no content at all.

Is there a way to tell .NET to not try to process the content of asp files, and only launch the HttpModule?

Maybe I'm even going down the wrong route here...I just want a block of .NET code to execute anytime a HTTP request is made to a certain directory, regardless of file extension, and then handle the request normally.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could sound like a MIME type issue?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

> Earlier versions of IIS include a
>   wildcard character MIME mapping, which
>   permits IIS to serve any file
>   regardless of its extension. IIS 6.0
>   does not include this wildcard
>   character MIME mapping and does not
>   serve any type of extension that is
>   not defined at the MimeMap node in the
>   IIS metabase.

To define a MIME type for a specific extension, follow these steps:

- Open the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC), right-click the local computer name, and then click Properties.
- Click MIME Types.
  Click New.
- In the Extension box, type the file name extension that you want (for example, .pdb).
- In the MIME Type box, type application/octet-stream.
- Apply the new settings. Note that you must restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service or wait for the worker process to recycle for the changes to take effect. In this example, IIS now serves files with the .pdb extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--I hadn't thought of this, and probably would've encountered this error somewhere down the line. Unfortunately though, the error isn't coming from IIS--it's coming from .NET.

Comment: The error makes perfect sense, too--I understand that .NET cannot parse ASP files. ASP files are handled by a completely different DLL. I just can't seem to figure out a way to get IIS to execute some .NET code, and THEN process the request normally, whether it be through ASP or something else.

Comment: ah, sorry... missed the "...  and then handle the request normally.". I don't think that is possible in IIS6, you would have to use IIS 7 or 7.5 which has the option to run managed code for all requests. In IIS6 you're only option for hooking up code that runs on every request is to use ISAPI filters which is written in C++